# Usage of "in" or 'on' with ''deal'

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I came across the following two sentences, but I can't find out the reason or different meaning in two sentence for using on and in before the deal. Could I switch them around?

> There is talk that Airbus could snatch even more market share ***in*** that deal.
>   They have made a killing ***on*** the deal

Comment: Not idiomatically. One has a *share **in** something* but makes *a profit **on** something* (a killing being a big profit). It's more usual to obtain greater market share **through** a deal or **as the result of** a deal..

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the meaning.

It's about that fact that *share* takes "in" for its complement, and *killing* (in that sense) takes "on". There's no way to predict this: it's just part of the information about the words that you need to learn.

Comment: in the transaction, in the deal, in the situation. and idiom: to make a killing on [something].